# Register for remote notification at iOS startup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, app-startup

I'm using voip background mode to make it start on iOS boot.
I put into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions all code that I want to start on boot, but if I try to register for remote notification it doesn't work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastboot"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

If I read "lastboot" key on standardUserDefaults I can see that app was started on system startup,but if I try to send a notification nothing append.

From the logs I can see that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is called on startup.

Remote notification works well if I open manually the app.

My App is not for the App Store, but for non jailbroken devices.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to run the app interactively at least once in order to accept the notification permission prompt

Comment: Yes, but after the reboot it should work normally.

Comment: So are you saying if you don't add the voip flag to your info.plist you can register and receive push notifications?

Comment: Perhaps I have not explained well. If I open the app manually I receive push notifications (with or without voip flag). When the app is opened at startup I do not receive notifications. I've fixed the equivocal in my question.

Comment: Do you mean you are not getting app notification badge when the app in background and getting badge when its manually launched?